# undefined method `pictures' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, paperclip

I'm making a photo gallery using paperclip and keep getting this error

```
undefined method `pictures' for nil:NilClass
```

when creating a new picture. I have all of my associations set up and like

gallery -> has_many :pictures
picture -> belongs_to :gallery

and in my **pictures.controller** I have

```
def create
  @picture = @gallery.pictures.new(picture_params)
  respond_to do |format|
  if @picture.save
    format.html { redirect_to @picture, notice: 'Picture was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @picture }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @picture.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

I've spent the last day trying to figure this out.

Comment: Where is `@gallery` defined or set?

Comment: @lurker it's not set. I figured that was why it wasn't working. How can I set gallery in order for the picture to have belong to a gallery_id?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `@gallery.pictures.new(picture_params)` with `Picture.new(params)`?

Comment: It depends upon the overall design. If this request for `create` came from a form with a Gallery object, then the gallery object should come through that path. If you're just creating a picture, then `Picture.new(params)` is the correct approach.

Answer (score 2):

All we can really tell you based on what is posted is that `@gallery` is nil. You actually have to assign something to `@gallery`, Rails contains no boilerplate code to populate that variable for you.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. So how should I set @gallery in order to assign a picture to a gallery id?

Comment: As you would any other model; `@gallery = Gallery.find(gallery_id_goes_here)`

Comment: I've tried that and it still throws the same error? Very weird.

Comment: Not to mention when I do that they all go to gallery_id 1 no matter what gallery_id I'm under.